# htaccess doesn't deny PHP access to files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, permissions, debian

I'm having problems with my **Apache2** WebServer. I run **LAMP** on a VPS *(Debian 9, 64bit)*.
I have two VirtualHosts, Alpha and Beta.
Each VirtualHost has a different DocumentRoot: Alpha has /var/www/A, and Beta has /var/www/B.
The problem is that I don't want **Beta** can include /var/www/**A**/index.php on his files, and the same is for **Alpha**: I don't want he can include /var/www/**B**/index.php (and all other documents) in his files.
How can I do this? I already tryed lots of method using .htaccess but nothing worked, for example:

```
Order Allow, Deny
Deny from All
Allow from mydomain.com
```

Thank you! Hope in an answer...is so important :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Which version of Apache are you using? Apache 2.4, the latest, uses the [Require directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require) instead of the old `Order`,`Deny` and `Allow` directives.

Comment: Thank you! The version is Apache 2.4.25...I tried Require too..but I don't know which prompt shoud I put actually: I searched on internet but nothing to help :(

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't read completely your question and didn't fully comprehend that you were trying to block PHP and not http requests. My bad for reading too fast :) I added a comment on the first answer to help you doing what you seek.

Comment: `.htaccess` works on the HTTP request. When you call `include /var/www/A/index.php` in your PHP script you are not making an HTTP request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you speak about PHP's `include` it is not possible to achieve this with htaccess, since you could include any file in the whole file system that can be read by the Apache user.

A solution would be to have a program that can run Apache with different user access depending on the document root, so you can only include (read) the files inside the document root defined for the virtual host, I think it is possible using an Apache module or some other Unix program (I don't remember), it is the same solution that is used by web hosting providers when they give you a folder inside the file system and you can only read the files inside this folder, they usually give you a user name (a Unix user) which have only read access to a specific folder and also Apache run with the rights with this user and so on for PHP.

Comment: Yes..I would be an idea...how can I do that? Thank you!

Comment: @ankabout is right, PHP doesn't really care about the Apache configuration. But you can use the [VHostUser directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_privileges.html#vhostuser) for specifying a different user for each virtualhost, and then manage the folder permissions of each in Debian.

Comment: @benjamin And how do I use it? Should I declare the UserDirective for each host right? And than? How do I resolve the PHP problem? Thank you 

Comment: @BenjaminC. Wow that seems a nice approach, I thought he would need a whole module to achieve this, but if there is an Apache directive for it that it is cool. But be aware Andrea that is a serious domain and you need to read carefully the documentation on this part to avoid security breachs.

Comment: @AndreaDeAngelis One user per VirtualHost seems fine, and then you would create each user in Debian with `adduser`. Given my limited knowledge in Linux permissions I will stop here and let you search for it. Also, I cannot emphasize enough @ankabout's advice about reading carefully anything that's talking about users permissions in Debian, because badly set permissions can be a lot more harmful than just including PHP from another folder.